# ASP.net c#. How do I parse an atom feed from a blog

Tags: c#, asp.net, atom-feed

The feed is at:

http://latestpackagingnews.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

The tags I want are:

```xml
<entry>
    <published></published>
    <title></title>
    <content></content>
</entry>
```

I don't care about anything else, all I want to do is loop these!  Please don't post tutorial links I've tried a bunch and just can't get any to work.  Treat me like an idiot please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a look at the System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Atom10FeedFormatter class. (System.ServiceModel.dll)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Atom10FeedFormatter formatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("http://latestpackagingnews.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default"))
    {
        formatter.ReadFrom(reader);
    }

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in formatter.Feed.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] {2}", item.PublishDate, item.Title.Text, ((TextSyndicationContent)item.Content).Text);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I 'using System.ServiceModel;' at the top of my page it can't find anything though?

Comment: Have you added the System.ServiceModel.dll to your references? Also the full namespace is System.ServiceModel.Syndication