# How to get certain elements inside an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, sharepoint-2013

I am querying my SP list like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myspsite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('the%20title')/items");

request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(readStream);
response.Close();
readStream.Close();
```

which gives me the following:

```
<feed xml:base="http://myspsite/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <id>090ds-211312-asdadsasd</id>
  <title />
  <updated>2011-03-16T15:33:25Z</updated>
  <entry m:etag="&quot;7&quot;">
    <id>a4846531-dae6-413c-bbbe-b3012342ewerred0d1</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.My.ListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'0eef-a924-471e-80f0-8d71erwsdf3d6d')/Items(10)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2012-03-16T15:33:25Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">38</d:Id>
        <d:ContentTypeId>0x010400C64826486CBEE74BBFF0werwerewsdfD</d:ContentTypeId>
        <d:Title>This is my Title</d:Title>
        <d:Body>This is the body</d:Body>
        <d:Summaries>This is the body summary</d:Summaries>
        <d:Include m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Include>
        <d:Add_Date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-10-07T04:00:00Z</d:Add_Date>
        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">38</d:ID>
        <d:OData__UIVersionString>1.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
        <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">69504c8e-6897-49e6-926d-d54c900524e5</d:GUID>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry m:etag="&quot;7&quot;">
    <id>a4846531-dae6-413c-bbbe-b301234234ewd0d1</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.My.ListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'0ee1d7ef-a924-471e-80f0-8d71erwsdf3d6d')/Items(38)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2012-03-16T15:33:25Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">38</d:Id>
        <d:ContentTypeId>0x010400C64826486CBEE7sdfsfdsdf3D</d:ContentTypeId>
        <d:Title>This is my Title</d:Title>
        <d:Body>This is the body</d:Body>
        <d:Summaries>This is the body summary</d:Summaries>
        <d:Include m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Include>
        <d:Add_Date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-10-07T04:00:00Z</d:Add_Date>
        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">38</d:ID>
        <d:OData__UIVersionString>1.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
        <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">69504c8e-6897-49e6-926d-d54c900524e5</d:GUID>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  //... more entry
</feed>
```

How can I get the `d:Title` and `d:Body` for each `entry`?

I tried to use:

```
foreach (XElement element in xd.Descendants("entry"))
{
  Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

but that didn't work.

Please help me get the nodes in `entry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    XName properties = XName.Get("properties", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
    XName title = XName.Get("Title", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
    XName body = XName.Get("Body", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
    var result = xd.Descendants(properties).Select(en => new { title = en.Element(title), body = en.Element(body) });
```

Comment: Nope. It is not working. It is showing as, `Enumeration yielded no results`

Comment: Sadly runtime error. `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.`

Comment: @Si8 have incoparated changes due to namespace

Comment: @CPR43 Thank you. That is working for me... awesome!

Comment: Any idea how can I convert it to JSON to send via Web API?

Comment: if you are using mvc controllerr, it will have a return type Json(Object) which automatically converts the object to json , but you may fisrt have to convert these xelement results to the class structure you need before json serialization.

Comment: Yes that's true... I only want the value from each row/column and not the element node... hmmmm

Comment: Yeah .. also it will be great if you could accept this answer

Comment: One last question, how do I add a  `where` in the `Select`? Let's say `where title="testing1"`?

Comment: xd.Descendants(properties).Where(p=>p.Element(title).value == "testing1").Select(p=>p);

Comment: One more thing, There is a node "link" in the returned data but when I use `Descendants` it can't find it. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please assist me with this if possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907980/how-to-combine-multiple-nodes-into-one-from-a-atom-feed

Answer (score 2):

You should use the XName instead of tag name.

```
 foreach (XElement element in xd.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry"))
            {
              Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
```

//To read the d:title and d:body,

```
XName title = XName.Get("Title", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            XName body = XName.Get("Body", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            foreach (XElement element in xd.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry"))
            {
                //Iterate the child element [ element.Descendants(title)], to get the title and body
                //To simply the code, I used FirstOrDefault here
                Console.WriteLine(element.Descendants(title).FirstOrDefault().Value);
                Console.WriteLine(element.Descendants(body).FirstOrDefault().Value);               

            }
```

This is working for me.

Comment: Me too... Thank you... How do I get the `d:Title` and `d:Body`, Can I treat the element as a regular XML node?

Comment: I'm trying that, but hopefully you should use as XName.

Comment: Me too... Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I +1 your answer.

Comment: Can you please assist with this if possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907980/how-to-combine-multiple-nodes-into-one-from-a-atom-feed Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is not a standard xml but an atom feed.
Try this: [ASP.net c#. How do I parse an atom feed from a blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103522/asp-net-c-how-do-i-parse-an-atom-feed-from-a-blog)
Or google a framework